# pandas: group dataframe rows into different clusters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, grouping

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'forms_a_cluster': [False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False,
True, True, False, True, True, True, False],
'cluster_number':[False, False, 1, 1, 1, False, False, False,
              2, 2, False, 3, 3, 3, False]})
```

The idea is that I have some criteria which, when certain rows have met it, selects those cases as True, and when consecutive rows meet the criteria, they then form a cluster. I want to be able to label each cluster as `cluster_1`, `cluster_2`, `cluster_3` etc. I've given an example of the hoped for output with the column `cluster_number`. But I have no idea how to do this, given that in the real data, I have to do it many times on different datasets which have a different number of rows and the cluster sizes will be different every time. Do you have any idea how to go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filtered [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add the `False`:

```
df['cluster_number'] = (df[df['forms_a_cluster']]
                        .groupby('id').ngroup().add(1)
                        .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
                        )
```

Output:

```
    id  forms_a_cluster cluster_number
0    1            False          False
1    1            False          False
2    2             True              1
3    2             True              1
4    2             True              1
5    3            False          False
6    3            False          False
7    3            False          False
8    4             True              2
9    4             True              2
10   5            False          False
11   6             True              3
12   6             True              3
13   6             True              3
14   7            False          False
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, unfortunately I framed my question wrong so I need to post again with it framed properly. Basically my real life data doesn't have the Id column that I included.

Comment: here I reposted with it formulated correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578556/pandas-add-a-grouping-variable-to-clusters-of-rows-that-meet-a-criteria

Comment: @stevezissou I've seen it, I answered ;)

Comment: You might want to close this one btw

Comment: nice one, thanks for the great solution, will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to do this:

```
df["cluster_number"] = False
df.loc[df["forms_a_cluster"], "cluster_number"] = (
    df.loc[df["forms_a_cluster"]].groupby(["id", "forms_a_cluster"]).ngroup() + 1
)


print(df)

    id  forms_a_cluster cluster_number
0    1            False          False
1    1            False          False
2    2             True              1
3    2             True              1
4    2             True              1
5    3            False          False
6    3            False          False
7    3            False          False
8    4             True              2
9    4             True              2
10   5            False          False
11   6             True              3
12   6             True              3
13   6             True              3
14   7            False          False
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, unfortunately I framed my question wrong so I need to post again with it framed properly. Basically my real life data doesn't have the Id column that I included.

Comment: here I reposted with it formulated correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578556/pandas-add-a-grouping-variable-to-clusters-of-rows-that-meet-a-criteria